# how to place this image within the text?

Tags: graphics

I would like to place the photo (claude shannon) that is in the screenshot in this text exactly like that, I have a lot to try but I can not do it I would be grateful to help me thanks[image]

Comment: @mohammeddjeridate: welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: Look at the packages `floatflt`, `wrapfig`, `window`, `cutwin`, and a few more. I think each of these can do what you want. They do have their quirks, however. Especially if there is a list in their neighbourhood like in the first example.

Answer (score 3):

Try this below coding:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{wrapfig}

\title{Figure Clarification}
\author{writeLaTeX}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\begin{wrapfigure}{R}{0.3\textwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.25\textwidth]{bio1.eps}
\end{wrapfigure}

Sample text Sample text Sample text Sample text Sample text Sample text Sample text Sample text Sample text Sample text Sample text Sample text Sample text Sample text Sample text Sample text Sample textSample text Sample text Sample text Sample text Sample text Sample text Sample text Sample text Sample text Sample text Sample text Sample text Sample text Sample text Sample text Sample text Sample textSample text Sample text Sample text Sample text Sample text Sample text Sample text Sample text Sample text Sample text Sample text Sample text Sample text Sample text Sample text Sample textSample text Sample text Sample text Sample text Sample text Sample text Sample text Sample text Sample text Sample text Sample text Sample text Sample text Sample text Sample text Sample text Sample textSample text Sample text Sample text Sample text Sample text Sample text Sample text Sample text Sample text Sample text Sample text Sample text Sample text Sample text Sample text Sample textSample text Sample text Sample text Sample text Sample text Sample text Sample text Sample text Sample text Sample text Sample text Sample text Sample text Sample text Sample text Sample text Sample textSample text Sample text Sample text Sample text Sample text Sample text Sample text Sample text Sample text Sample text Sample text Sample text Sample text Sample text Sample text Sample textSample text 
\end{document}
```

Hope this will works for you...:)

Comment: @mohameddjeridane Good to hear that the answer helped you. If you are satisfied with the solution, please consider accepting it (by clicking on the checkmark ✓, see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows others that the question is solved and will remove it from the list of unanswered questions. As a bonus, this will not only give a reward to the answer, but you will get 2 reputation points, too.